in RStudio Server (not CLI R, which works), R cannot load required shared object file (libproj.so.25) even though file exists
I've been using RStudio on a cluster for which I do not have sudo rights, which complicates matters. I've been trying to install and use the EnhancedVolcano package, which I've managed to install somewhat manually by compiling the relevant dependencies (proj4 was one of these) and then using BiocManager::install("EnhancedVolcano") as usual. This command was successful.
I believe that the files are all in the correct location, and all the relevant environment variables are set correctly, but the load fails in RStudio Server specifically:
> library(EnhancedVolcano)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: ggrepel
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘EnhancedVolcano’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/tubergene/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/proj4/libs/proj4.so':
  libproj.so.25: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/tubergene/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1" "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                    
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                           "/usr/lib/R/library"                               
> Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
[1] "/usr/lib/R/lib:/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server:/home/tubergene/.local/lib"

The weird part is, I am able to load the library in the command line version of R:
tubergene@cluster:~/.../proj4/libs$ R

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) -- "Bird Hippie"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> library(EnhancedVolcano)
Loading required package: ggplot2
Loading required package: ggrepel
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'ggalt':
  method                  from   
  grid.draw.absoluteGrob  ggplot2
  grobHeight.absoluteGrob ggplot2
  grobWidth.absoluteGrob  ggplot2
  grobX.absoluteGrob      ggplot2
  grobY.absoluteGrob      ggplot2
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/tubergene/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1"
[2] "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"                    
[3] "/usr/lib/R/site-library"                          
[4] "/usr/lib/R/library"                               
> Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")
[1] "/usr/lib/R/lib:/lib:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/lib/server:/home/tubergene/.local/lib"
> Sys.getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH")

Why might there be a difference in the behaviour of R in the command line mode, and RStudio Server?

Maybe the issue is that you compiled proj4 locally in your user directory, so RStudio can’t access it. This likely happens because it wasn’t installed globally. You could ask the system admin to install proj4 and other stuff globally, or adjust the permissions so RStudio can access the local installation.
